# How to Parse a Json Data Response from an API call on Ionic as Below

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework

I made an api call and get a response as below, shown on console

My Api Provider:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class RestapiProvider {

apiUrl = 'http://example.com/api/GetItemByCategory?cat_id=1&merchant_id=1&json=true';

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    //console.log('Hello RestapiProvider Provider');
  }

getItembyCategory() {
     return new Promise(resolve => {
        this.http.get(this.apiUrl).subscribe(data => {
      resolve(data);
      console.log(data);
    }, err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    });
}
```

Console.log(data) shows

```
[object Object]: {code: 1, details: Object, msg: "success..", request: "{"cat_id":"1","merchant_id":"1","json":"true"}"}
```

[console.log(data)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEdso.jpg)

I need to parse the json data on '**`details: Object`**'

I tried **`console.log(data.details)`** 
got error:

`Unable to get property 'details' of undefined or null reference`

**UPDATE**

I was trying to use `map` operator as below

```
this.http.get(this.apiUrl).map(data => data.json()).subscribe(data => {
  resolve(data);
  console.log(data);
}
```

Got another error: `property json does not exist on type 'Object'`

Please let me know how to make it work on ionic 3.

Regards

[console.log SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEdso.jpg)

Comment: cant get what you want?

Comment: how about: `console.log(data.details)`

Comment: Unable to get property 'details' of undefined or null reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I manage to go through the 'details' with

```
data['details'];
```

and 'item'

```
data['details']['item'];
```

Thanks for all the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try like this:

Import the toPromise operator:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
```

Then turn your observable into a promise with it's help. No need to map the response to Json as you use the new Angular `HttpClient`, it is mapped by default.

```
getItembyCategory() {
 return this.http.get(this.apiUrl)
  .toPromise()
  .then((data: any) => {
     console.log('Success', data.details);
     return data;
  })
  .catch(err => {
     console.log('Error', err);
     return err;
  })
}
```

This way the code is so much cleaner. It is tested and works. If it doesn't then you should check your apiUrl.

**Edited**

The reason you receive the error `property 'details' does not exist on type 'Object'` is because you need to give a type to the data object you receive (other than the default `Object`). I updated the example with this:

```
(data: any) => {
  console.log(data.details);
  return data;
}
```

This is so much better than the ugly square brackets in `data['details']` :).

Comment: yes the code works. it returns json object as the pictured attached above. the problem is how to parse the nested json objects or arrays inside 'details'? i tried console.log(data.details). it returns error: property 'details' does not exist on type 'Object'